# Is there a way to restart the bus using RabbitMq with MassTransit?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I want to restart the bus connection using RabbitMq with MassTransit, the first idea was to stop the connection and start it again but this did not work. Is there something more specific or a better way to do that?

```
await bus.StopAsync();
await bus.StartAsync(source.Token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are on a current version of MassTransit, you can do exactly that to restart the bus.

You can see in [this unit test](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/tests/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Tests/StartStop_Specs.cs#L35) that the bus is started and stopped without issue.

```cs
await bus.StartAsync(TestCancellationToken);
await bus.StopAsync(TestCancellationToken);

await bus.StartAsync(TestCancellationToken);
await bus.StopAsync(TestCancellationToken);
```

Comment: I'm using the 8.0.8 version. When I try to start the bus again I'm getting the following exception: System.OperationCanceledException: 'The operation was canceled.'

Comment: Another question, how can I see if the bus restarted?

Comment: Look at the logs, and there are extensive tests that restart the bus, so I'd suspect your cancellationToken on the Start call.

Comment: Is this referencing IBusControl?

Comments on [the interface](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.Abstractions/IBusControl.cs) seem to suggest that you shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: @FriedLychees the bus can be stopped/started as needed. The comment is likely outdated.